# Вопрос о сути Factory

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, factory

Верно ли, что фабрику необходимо использовать только тогда, когда при создании нового объекта нужно учитывать предыдущие объекты, внутренние переменные фабрики и внешние переменные?

Приведу пример:

```
interface Zone{
    Enemy toCreate(String name);
}
class Zone101 implements Zone{
    final int enemyToIncreaseTheirDifficult = 3;
    int countOfCreatedEnemies = 0;
    int difficult = 0;

    public Enemy toCreate(String name) {
        if(name.equals("Zombie")) {
            if(countOfCreatedEnemies % enemyToIncreaseTheirDifficult == 0) {
                difficult++;
            }
            countOfCreatedEnemies++;
            return new Zombie(difficult);

        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
class Enemy{
    private int difficult;

    Enemy(int difficult){
        this.difficult = difficult;
    }
}
class Zombie extends Enemy{
    int timesToReLife;

    Zombie(int difficult){
        super(difficult);
        timesToReLife = difficult + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100884/discussion-on-question-by-miron----factory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта формулировка охватывает не все случаи.
Фабрика также нужна тогда, когда нам нужно добавить некоторую новую логику в конструктор класса A. Нам не придется производить изменения в классе A - добавлять конструкторы или создавать методы toCreate. Достаточно лишь создать фабрику.